# I have a line of code in a non-component React file I need tested that doesn't get hit by tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm aiming for 100% test coverage, and I have a file called `agent.js` which has:

```
export const requests = {
    get: url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()),
    post: (url, body) =>
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()) //**this line lacks coverage**
}

export const Gatherings = {
    getAll: () =>
        requests.get(API_ROOT + '/gatherings'),
    postAll: () =>
        requests.post(API_ROOT + '/gatherings')
}
export default {
    Gatherings
}
```

I have tests that cover everything **except** the line I've indicated in the fetch call. How can I get that tested?

Comment: how does your test look like? are you mocking fetch's response? are you awaiting till response is returned and processed?

Answer (score 1):

You can test and get 100% code coverage for `requests.post` by doing the following:

```
import { requests } from './agent';

test('requests.post', async () => {  // use an async test function
  const realFetch = global.fetch;  // save the real fetch
  const spy = jest.fn();
  global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ json: spy }));  // mock fetch
  await requests.post('the url', 'the body');  // wait for the Promise to resolve
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'the body',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });  // SUCCESS
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
  global.fetch = realFetch;  // restore the real fetch
})
```

Comment: thanks! However, how can I get that to work when it's not the first test in the file? Also, can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934996/i-can-unit-test-an-alert-to-show-up-but-not-whats-in-the-alert-or-the-onpress ? thanks!!!

Comment: @user11039951 This test won't interfere with any other test since it restores everything it modifies...is there something in an earlier test that interferes with this test?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mocking and testing the POST call too? Maybe that's why. If not you can do:

```
 /* istanbul ignore next */
 }).then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: @user11039951 Then only one solution left if you absolutely need 100% test coverage

Comment: @user11039951 it's for people who really want 100% coverage. you mark places where the coverage tool doesn't work